# Separating code - modularising

Tags: oop

When developing how useful is it to create small classes to represent little data structures?  For example say as a simplified example, a program is using an array of strings to represent names of something, e.g. cars.  Instead of just keeping this array inside a method or class, how useful is it to separate this and make it it own class?  This way I am thinking that it can be responsible for itself and more actions can be performed on it - validation, etc. which can all be kept separate.  Also, it can be reused easily throughout the system.  But then where does it stop, i.e. in the car example, you could then go on to create a car object etc.  It really can be never ending can't it?

Comment: I think it would help if you made your question more clear. Obviously OO code can go too far sometimes *in my opinion*, but what exactly are you asking here? I see a scenario, but it seems pretty vague.

Comment: ok, so say i need to have a collection of objects, which will all essentially be strings as names and maybe a description again in string format and any other attribiutes that may be added.  Is it best to just keep this inside what ever class requires it or is it better to make this an object in its own right, even though it has only a few attributes that are strings.  Also if its going to be its own object then could its data validation be handled by its own constructor instead of handling this elsewhere also.  It seems logical to me but perhaps a little over the top.

Comment: The goal of good design is to ultimately provide maintainability and clarity with no true hard and fast rules.  You could certainly go on, ad nauseum, and model the whole universe for which your project may interact.

This is where it's important to understand what objects are in your domain and, having modeled that, you will know when a simple collection of a given object will suffice, or if a more logical unit is required.

Answer (score 1):

There are several guidelines I use to determine when I need to refactor a data structure into its own class:

- **Am I storing a lot of interrelated data?**  If you find yourself storing a couple of arrays, and manipulating them as a unit, it's probably best to store a single array containing objects.
- **Are these data structures exposed to other classes?**  If other classes are directly exposed to the data, it's probably best to encapsulate the data in its own class, which makes it easy to keep the conceptual and actual models separate.
- **Do I find myself frequently performing operations on the data?**  It might be fine to store an array of names, but if you start adding methods like `validateName` and `checkName` to the wrapping class, it might be a good idea to refactor and place those methods on a `Name` class itself.

Keep in mind: it's often a lot easier and cleaner to put a decent object model in place up front than to try and graft one on after the fact.  You shouldn't do it arbitrarily, but as you're working through your program you should pay attention to when it becomes difficult to control the data structures you have--that's a good sign that you should refactor them, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to do this as soon as you are repeating code to operate on the data structure.

Chris B. makes a great point about interrelated data. See the [Extract Class](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) refactoring example.